# AAC/ADTS to WAV in Flutter/Django

Tags: django, flutter, audio, speech-recognition, record

My Team and I are building a speech-to-text application for a specific purpose.
The frontend is in **Flutter** and the backend is in **Django**

I am using the [flutter_sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound) package for Flutter and the only Codec it supports for recording audio is Codec.aacADTS and I am able to save the file using .aac or .adts

On the backend (Django), we're using the [Speech Recognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) Library and when using the .aac or .adts file with this, it gives an error: `ValueError("Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format")`

We tried using another .wav file and speech recognition works.
So, do I need to convert the .aac/.adts file to a .wav file?
How should I do it, and should it be on the frontend or the backend? Any library/code snippets to help me with that?

**Frontend Code (Flutter)**

```
Future startRecord() async {
    setState(() {
      isRecording = true;
    });

    Directory? dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    await recorder.startRecorder(
        toFile: "${dir!.path}/audio.aac", codec: Codec.aacADTS);
  }

  Future stopRecorder() async {
    final filePath = await recorder.stopRecorder();
    final file = File(filePath!);
    uploadAudio(file);
    print('Recorded file path: $filePath');

    setState(() {
      isRecording = false;
      audioFile = file;
    });
  }
```

**Backend Code (Django)**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def speech_to_text(request):
    conn = mongo_conn()
    audio_file_ID = request.GET['AudioFileID']
    audio_file = download_audio(conn, audio_file_ID)

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.AudioData(audio_file) as source:
        # listen for the data (load audio to memory)
        audio_data = r.record(source)
        # recognize (convert from speech to text)
        text = r.recognize_google(audio_data)
        print(text)

    return JsonResponse({'text': text}, safe=False)
```

Comment: Do it in the backend, and use e.g. ffmpeg, either via subprocess or https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python.

Comment: It would be best to capture the audio as PCM and stick a simple WAV header on it. That way you won't lose any quality with compression/decompression. But, beware, the file size will be large. For speech recognition, use at least 16kHz sample rate and 16 bits of PCM. Though any higher than that won't make much difference.

Comment: @RichardHeap does flutter_sound allows to use PCM? If so, how? I tried PCM16wav, it says invalid Codec

Comment: No idea - check out mic_stream and/or record